# Finding a difference then the largest value over time

Tags: sql-server

How do you get the row that gained most value over a period of time out of the large group set?

I've seen some overly-complicated variations on this question, and none with a good answer. I've tried to put together the simplest possible example:

Given a table like the one below, with row#, ID, year, and value columns, how would you find an ID that gained the most value and display the difference as a new column in the output?

| Column A | ID | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 322 | 2012 | 150,000 |
| row 2 | 322 | 2013 | 165,000 |
| row 3 | 344 | 2012 | 220,000 |
| row 4 | 344 | 2013 | 290,000 |

Desired output:

| ID | Value | Value_Gained |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 344 | 290,000 | 70,000 |

```
SELECT  id, year, value
FROM table
WHERE value = (SELECT MAX(value) FROM table);
```

Comment: "*... and display the difference as a new column in the output?*" - What happens if your ID has more than two values? In that case which are the values you make the difference on?

Comment: SELECT MAX(BlaBlaBla) - MIN(BlaBlaBla)  GROUP BY

Comment: @lemon each ID only has one value associated with it in a single year, if there is a 3rd I suppose I'd get the difference between earliest and latest years.

Comment: Execute this select: SELECT TOP(1) MAX(V) - MIN(V) GROUP BYYY ID ORDER BY 1 DESC

Comment: Note that `MIN` and `MAX` won't work if the values are not strictly increasing throughout years. Also ordering should happen on the value, not on the difference.

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The `FIRST_VALUE` window function will help you get values between last and first year for each of your ids. Then it's sufficient to order by your biggest values and getting one row using `TOP(N)`.

```
SELECT TOP(1)
       ID,
       FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Year] DESC) AS [Value], 
       FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Year] DESC)
          - FIRST_VALUE([Value]) OVER(PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Year]) AS [ValueGained]
FROM tab
ORDER BY [Value] DESC
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LvxZNalM).

Comment: This doesn't return the value that gained most, but rather the one with highest value? Or maybe that's what the user wanted, it's somewhat unclear from the question